# Free drawing using gdi - Issue with alpha color

Tags: c++, mfc, draw, gdi, alpha

I let user to draw on a form.
I start when my app get the mouse down even.
I end when it gets the mouse up event.
I draw on mousemove event.

I.E in mouse down event i get the StartPoint.
Then in mousemove i check, if mouse is still down then i draw according to the mouse position.
I draw using DrawLine function.
I save the previous point and draw to the new point i get in mousemove.
lets say mouse moved from P1(x1,y1),P2(x2,y2),P3(x3,y3) then i have line from P1 to P2 to P3.
Everything works as it should.
Problem starts when i draw with transparent color (i.e Alpha is 100 for example).
When i do that, P2 get painted twice. first time when line is drawn from p1 to p2 and second time when line drawn from p2 to p3.

When Alpha is 255 you do not see it since p2 color will not change when you over write it. It stays the pen color.
When you overwrite with alpha that is not equal to 255 then on each overwrite the color become darker with looks as small dots inside the line.

I have attached screenshot so you will see the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vA0k.png
Any solution to make lines with no dot in it?
do not forget that there can be many points in the line and it is free drawing so line is not Straight.
Each dot you see in the line was created on each call to mousemove.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious possibility would be to draw the whole line (from the start to the current point) with no transparency into an off-screen bitmap.

Then set the alpha channel for each pixel in that bitmap to the desired value (100, for your example).

Finally, use AlphaBlend to draw from that bitmap into the destination.

Comment: Hi. my app shows the user the drawing on the fly. as far as i understand from your solution, i only apply the drawing in the end after user release the mouse. but my app redraw on each mouse move. also i guess you mean to SetPixel func to set the alpha but my pen width is bigger then 1px and it is rounded pen.

Comment: @n12: No, I don't mean delaying the drawing until mouse release. Just where you're currently drawing to the screen, draw to the off-screen bitmap, then from there to the screen (using AlphBlend in the latter case). And no, you don't want to use SetPixel--it's quite slow.

Comment: 1)"Then set the alpha channel for each pixel" how do i do that? I have p1 and p2 - do i need to find the f(x) function and draw all points from x1 to x2? also do not forget that line width is not 1px width line.
2) what do i copy using the AlphBlend ? AlphBlend  copy rectangle to rectangle and i do not want to copy entire transparent rectangle/entire rectangle - but only the line. I think i am not follow you and i am sorry for that. hope you can give more info.

Comment: @n12: You copy the whole rectangle, but (for example) set the background to black, and the function to OR, so the black background has no effect. Here's an example using GDI+: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533955.aspx